# Auto calculation on a field in a model in Django RESTframework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So I have a model which has an attribute to be auto calculated when the api receives a POST request. The model is a bill model where the totalpayment is calculated on numberOfHours * paymentRate. Django does not allow me to do so by setting default value. Is there a way to do this?

Model

```
class Bill(models.Model):
    billID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    bill_dt = models.DateField()
    hours =  models.FloatField()
    workAssignmentID_fk = models.ForeignKey(WorkAssignment, null=True, default=None)
    totalPayment = models.FloatField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.bill_dt)

    def __str__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.bill_dt)
```

Serializer

```
class ReadBillSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    workAssignmentID_fk = ReadWorkAssignmentSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Bill
        fields = ('url', 'bill_dt', 'hours', 'workAssignmentID_fk', 'totalPayment')

class WriteBillSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Bill
        fields = ('url', 'bill_dt', 'hours', 'workAssignmentID_fk', 'totalPayment')
```

View

```
class BillViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Bill.objects.all()

    def get_serializer_class(self, *args, **kwargs):        
        if self.request.method == 'POST' or self.request.method == 'PUT':
            return WriteBillSerializer
        return ReadBillSerializer
```

In the model Bill, I want totalPayment = hours * workAssignmentID_fk.paymentRate.

paymentRate is an attribute in the workAssignmentID_fk.

Comment: Please add some code for serializers, models and views. Are `numberofhours` and `paymentRate` model fields? Are you using a model serializer?

Comment: Thank you @RahulGupta for a quick response. I have edited the question. Please have a look

Comment: How do we get `workAssignmentID_fk` object in case POST request

Comment: Is this passed in the post data? If yes, is there a serializer for `WorkAssignment` model also?

Comment: The workAssignmentID_fk  in the POST is just a URL to the object.
eg. `http://API_URL/WorkAssignment/4/`
But if it is GET request it would return in a JSON substructure format.

Comment: Okay. posted a solution. check if the solution works for your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override [`perform_create()`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/) function in your view and pass the value of `totalPayment` to the `save()` method of serializer.

`perform_create()` is called when saving a new object instance. You can use this object creation hook.

```
class BillViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Bill.objects.all()

    def get_serializer_class(self, *args, **kwargs):        
        if self.request.method == 'POST' or self.request.method == 'PUT':
            return WriteBillSerializer
        return ReadBillSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        hours = serializer.validated_data['hours'] # get the value of hours
        work_assignment_object = <get_the_workAssignmentID_fk_object_from_passed_url>
        payment_rate = work_assignment_object.paymentRate # get the value of 'paymentRate' from work assignment object
        total_payment = hours*payment_rate # calculate value of total payment
        serializer.save(total_payment=total_payment, workAssignmentID_fk=work_assignment_object) # pass the value of total payment to be saved and the work assignment object
```

Comment: So if I have other attributes in the bill model, do I have to pass them as well in the serializer.save method?

Comment: You have to pass those attributes only which you are not `POSTing` to the view so that object is saved with all the required attributes. I have assumed you are not passing only 2 fields `workAssignmentID_fk` object and `totalPayment` in the  post data, all other fields you are passing. So when object is being saved, it will get those 2 fields from `.save()` kwargs and other fields from `serializer.validated_data`.

Comment: Great! Don't forget to accept the answer if it was useful to you. http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers It might help others having the same issue. :)